# open custom url scheme via Spotify Apps API

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

From a Spotify app I want to communicate with a native application that has been registered with a custom URL scheme. I am testing with a clickable anchor tag

```
<a href="myscheme:/test">open custom url scheme</a>
```

as well as javascript code

```
location.href = "myscheme:/test";
```

which both work fine from any browser. At first, nothing happened when I clicked the link/ran the JavaScript in Spotify. After extending the permissions in manifest.json to

```
    "RequiredPermissions": [
    "https://*",
    "http://*",
    "myscheme:/*"
]
```

I am getting this page in the content view for both cases (click and JS)

```
<head></head>    
<body>Error -302 when loading url myscheme:/test</body>
```

and the console output says

```
I [mainview:6886] Load complete (1) url: 
I [mainview:6886] Load complete (0) url: cef-error:
```

**Update**: For the scheme `mailto:` this seems to work just fine. Even without an explicit entry to `RequiredPermissions`.

**Update 2**: In more recent versions (e.g. 0.8.4.124) clicks on links with custom URIs have no effect to the content anymore. The log states:

```
W [CefAppInstance.cpp:49           ] App spotify:app:tutorial is not allowed to access resource: myscheme:/test
```

The `mailto:` still to works without explicit `RequiredPermissions`.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware this isn't supported in the Apps API.